# What does the phrase '痞痞的' mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

I tried to find out but I found that '痞' means constipation which I think would be highly unlikely in cases like this:

'痞痞的小小姐' or '痞痞的小家伙'

Comment: A cute hippy guy.

Answer (score 1):

痞 means bad, eg, 痞子 is like the English word "rogue". I have seldom seen the phrase "痞痞的", but i think it would mean somebody is naughty, like a scamp maybe.